# HTML2PDF no carga ciertas imagenes

Tags: php, html2pdf

Tengo un problema en varios dominios. Mediante ckeditor y elfinder selecciono una imagen para generar un pdf. El problema es que tengo el mismo código en varias webs y en algunas funciona y en otras no. El error es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ImageException' with message 'Unable to get
>   the size of the image

La Url si que es accesible desde el navegador.
He revisado la directiva **allow_url_fopen** y está activada.
Todos los dominios están bajo la misma suscripción de plesk y tienen la misma versión php.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Muchas gracias de antemano.